# Equivalent to GOTO in conditions, Python

Tags: python, conditional-statements, goto

Since there is no goto operator in Python, what technique can be used instead?

Condition
If it is true, go to thread 1, if is false, go to thread 2
In thread we do something small and after that we go to thread 2 where all other actions take place.

Comment: you can't goto across threads

Comment: Your question needs a _once over_, can you provide a little more?

Comment: Why would you put two pieces of code into threads, if only one of them is supposed to be run, based on a condition? Threads are for parallel execution, which apparently is not going to happen in your scenario. If I understand correctly, "thread2" is executed anyway, so the whole code from "thread1" should be executed based on your condition, the "thread2" code afterwards.

Comment: -1: That's not a GOTO.  That's locking.

Comment: Also, one of the greatest tech April's fool's jokes I've ever seen was the creation of a *functioning* [`goto`](http://entrian.com/goto/) module for Python.

Comment: From your comments below, it appears that by "goto thread" you mean execution of a particular piece of code. Both "goto" and "thread" are technical terms with precise semantics that have nothing whatsoever to do with what you mean. Your question is thus misleading and confusing. I suggest that (a) you invest a little time in learning the proper terminology, and (b) you invest a little effort in editing the question so that it makes sense. I suspect, however, that after (a), you will find that you know the answer to your question.

Comment: Why not?! ) Jumps between threads calls coroutines. Try to use Greenlet - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet for solving this task.

Answer (score 14):

> Since there is no goto operator in Python, what technique can be used instead?

Constructing your code logically and semantically.

```
if condition:
    perform_some_action()

perform_other_actions()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
def thread_1():
  # Do thread_1 type stuff here.

def thread_2():
  # Do thread_2 type stuff here.

if condition:
    thread_1()

# If condition was false, just run thread_2(). 
# If it was true then thread_1() will return to this point.
thread_2()
```

edit: I'm assuming that by "thread" you mean a piece of code (otherwise known as a subroutine or a function). If you're talking about threads as in parallel execution then you'll need more detail in the question.

Comment: Yes, i meant piece of code. Is it possible to place all these functions in a iteration "for"?

Comment: @Maks: Yes, of course. You can put almost anything in a for loop.

Answer (score 5):

To the best of my knowledge it's not present (thankfully), but you should check this [link](http://entrian.com/goto/)

> The "goto" module was an April Fool's joke, published on 1st April
>   2004. Yes, it works, but it's a joke nevertheless. Please don't use it in real code!

Comment: Do not tempt him to the Dark Side of Python programming :-) Luckily, it is written on the page, that it was just a April Fool's joke.

Answer (score 2):

Python is designed to support *good coding practices* and GOTO is not one of them. It may lead to unreadable program logic, if not used properly.

I suggest to learn code your program in a **Python way**, do not stick with (sometimes bad) habits from other programming languages. See Python documentation, real mature Python programs and learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
def thread1():
    #write your thread 1 code here

    print("entered no is 1")

def thread2():
    #write your thread 2 code here
    print("Number is greater or less then one.")

def main():
   a=input()
   if a==1:
   thread1()
   elif a<=1 or a>=1:
   thread2()
    #you can use recursion here in case if you want to use agin and again
    #if you want to print serveral time you can use looping.
    for i in range(4):
        main()
    #if you want to run goto forever and ever and ever then remove loop in 
    #this code.

#this code will enable you the equivalent of goto statement.
```

This is what I use every time in Python 3.x.